# SignalR clients update is not working

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

When i refresh any client page or any new client arrived, update from connected clients does not reach the new client.

I m using static global connection ids list, and send update to each connection.

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: i got solution from other threads

Comment: Could you add the solution here, in order that if somebody end up here they don't have to search somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I have customized ids in SignalR, and give them my generated UserID like this, and then send update with help of it.

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        var userId = "0";
        if (request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)request.User.Identity;
            userId = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;
        }
        return userId.ToString();
    }
}
```

In startup.cs

```
 var idProvider = new CustomUserIdProvider();
 GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);
```